# Plotly px.Scatter or go.Scatter Graph Unique Color/Symbol for specific points (Simple Map)

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, nan

I am attempting to create a simple site map using Plotly. I can't use scatter_geo because I am using known X, Y coordinates relative the site - not lat/long. px.Scatter or go.Scatter seem to be a viable option for a mostly simple map. So, I have a dataframe from that essentially looks like:

```
Location     Tag     x_coord    y_coord
Unit1        1-ABC     12.2       2.2
Unit1        2-DEF     -4.2       18
Unit2        3-HIJ      9          2
NaN          NaN        11         12
NaN          NaN        13         14
NaN          NaN        15         16
```

The NaNs are locations where a tag was NOT found, but the tool we used to do mapping continued to track an X, Y coordinate. Therefore, those points are quite useful as well.

Starting out, to create a simple scatter plot, I used:

```
fig = px.scatter(tagLocData, x=tagLocData['x_locations'], y=tagLocData['y_locations'])
```

Which worked fine for basic plotting, but I could not see the different locations. So, I moved to:

```
fig = px.scatter(tagLocData, x=tagLocData['x_locations'], y=tagLocData['y_locations'], color='Location')
```

However, this did not include the coordinates where nothing was found at the location, just the location:
[image]

I then tried adding a trace to a go.Figure via:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=tagLocData['x_locations'], y=tagLocData['y_locations'],\
                                mode='markers')) 


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=tagLocData['x_locations'], y=tagLocData['y_locations'], fillcolor='Location'))
```

Which yielded an expected error wanting a specific color for location, so I tried making a colorDict.

```
colors = ColorDict()
test = dict(zip(tagLocData['Location'].unique(), colors))

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=tagLocData['x_locations'], y=tagLocData['y_locations'],\
                                mode='markers', marker=test))
```

This overlayed the X, Y markers over the actual locations. I have tried a few other things as well with no luck. There are a lot of related questions out there but nothing that seems to hit on what I want to do.

How can I create a nice X, Y scatter plot with this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`px.scatter` will ignore `NaN` values, so you can fill the NaNs with a string like `"None"` and pass that dataframe to px.scatter:

```
fig = px.scatter(tagLocData.fillna("None"), x='x_coord', y='y_coord', color='Location')
```

[image]

Comment: Ah nice - I tried fillna to the whole DF but caused other issues. I did not know you could pass it directly to px.Scatter